# css/less editor which shows colors

Tags: css, editor, less

Is there a css editor (for Windows) which would show colors? Or more generally, editor that would always display a 6-characters hexadecimal values with a color background.

e.g. like this:

```
div.myclass {
  color: #ff8861;  <- the background (or foreground, doesn't matter) of #ff8861 has orange color in the editor
}
```

[Edit 1]: not a wysiwyg, just a rich text editor showing colors and syntax

[Edit 2]: ideally, it should also support LESS syntax

Comment: you need an online editor or desktop version?

Comment: better desktop, but online would also be ok, if there is no desktop solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in using Visual Studio, [ReSharper 6](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/02/css-support-in-resharper-6/) (in beta when that blog post was written, but released now) will show a thick underline in the specified color.

If you want something lighter-weight (or less expensive) than Visual Studio, the same folks who wrote ReSharper also make standalone IDEs. [WebStorm 3](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/11/phpstorm-webstorm-3-0-beta/) (currently in beta) shows color chips in the editor gutter. (Released versions may do this too; I can't find screenshots online.) Here's a screenshot I took from the beta; note the little gold square:

[image]

Comment: I confirm that the PHPStorm is showing colors in IDE, in .css and .less files.

Answer (score 5):

Try Crunch! - It's a LESS CSS editor that color codes, compiles and compresses. It's written in Adobe Air, so it's cross-platform. http://crunchapp.net/

Update - Visual Studio 2012 has a fantastic LESS editor, as a plug-in that you can install easily via the extensions manager. I believe that in VS2012, the extension is provided by Microsoft, and integrates with DotLess, and gives you a variety of options for when your LESS file is compiled (at compile, build or run times).

Comment: that would be the Web Essentials 2012 extension by Mads Kristensen

Answer (score 2):

I use Coda:

http://panic.com/coda/

It can display colors when editing CSS.

Comment: Then you should state that in your question :)

Answer (score 1):

http://KineticWing.com can shows colors inside less files. It highlights text in color. I mean #fff will appear as white text. It can handle #fff and #ffffff patterns.

Can work on windows/linux

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for that for a long time.
My solution is using **Netbeans** CSS Styles editor

**in the top menu click on Window -> Web -> CSS Styles**

Answer (score 0):

From 2 years my only one truth editor become **vs code** - perfect for JavaScript, to visualization CSS colors plugin: **COLORIZE**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Color Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ColorPreview) works fine for me on VS 2022.

[image]